# Редирект с домена на аккаунт Инстаграм

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Как сделать временное перенаправление с домена `mydomain.ru` на страницу аккаунт Инстаграм `https://www.instagram.com/myaccount/`

Для этого я создала в директории сайта файл `.htaccess` со строками:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.ru$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.instagram.com/myaccount/$1 [R=302,L]
```

Корректно ли?

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} old-site.ru
RewriteRule (.*) http://new-site.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
вот более правильный

Comment: Так а в чем сомнения? В итоге редиректит? Если htaccess лежит в корне сайта mydomain.ru и в это корень никакие другие сайты не смотрят, то RewriteCond тут избыточен и его можно не указывать.

Comment: @de_frag, хотела убедиться в правильности, а так да, редиректит. Проверила на различных браузерах, ошибое не обнаружила

Comment: @Alukard Nosferatu, единственная поправка не 301, а 302 (временное перенаправление)

Comment: @АлександраКузнецова я для примера привел, а там как угодно можно сделать

Comment: @de_frag RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} old-site.ru нужен, апач должен же знать откуда перенаправлять

Comment: @AlukardNosferatu при описанном мною условии: `один домен -> один сайт -> один корень сайта`, RewriteCond избыточен, в нем нет смысла. Если у вас к одному корню привязано несколько доменов/сайтов, а ридирект нужен только для одного домена/сайта, тогда `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}` имеет смысл.

Comment: @de_frag в принципе можно и без него, но с ним будет более грамотнее
"Строки RewriteCond - задают условия для срабатывания следующего за ними правила RewriteRule."